# rosbag playback speed

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

We have some sensor data that are saved as .csv files (data+timestamp) from a robot, which does not run ROS. To run some algorithms, I converted once such file into a ROS bag file using a python script.

After setting the /use_sim_time parameter and when playback this bag file with rosbag play --clock abc.bag, all the data seems to be flushed at once.

I need to know what determines the natural play speed of a bag file. I thought it is done using the header.stamp

Thank you in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48282/rosbag-playback-speed/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your Python script, I guess you were using Bag.write. Did you specify the `t` parameter and set it to the correct time stamp? As far as I know, that's the parameter that controls playback speed.

The system cannot use header.stamp for a simple reason: not every message has a stamp but rosbag needs time information. Also, the C++ rosbag library uses the raw (serialized) message data blobs to store them in the file. There is just no way to access the header without knowing the exact message definition.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-11-13**:
Thank you very much. Yeah it was the 't' paramater.